# How much will a round tube deflect under load?

Tags: material-science, elasticity, stress-strain

I'm trying to determine the materials I need to complete a hobby project, and I'm having trouble estimating how much flex a given steel tube would have under different configurations/loads.

My setup is a single round steel tube supported at 2 points in the center with radial loads on both ends. Such as:

```
 ___a____ ___b___ ____c___
/\       |       |       /\
La                       Lc
```

Where `b` is the distance between the 2 supports and `a` and `c` are distances between the supports and the end of the tube where loads `La` and `Lc` are attached.

Given an `Inner Diameter` and `Outer Diameter`of the tube and its `Modulus of Elasticity` are there equations that would describe the downward deflection at either ends (and maybe the upward deflection at the center of b)?

Comment: I do not entirely agree that this question has been put on hold as off-topic, since it is about the theory of statics. Ben have a look at the [Euler-Bernoulli beam theory](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Bernoulli_beam_theory).